# Is it possible to do SQL server database to other cloud mysql migration with AWS DMS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, mysqli, aws-dms

AWS DMS has schema conversion tool and other advanced features in database migration.So is it possible to do SQL server database inside a vm to some other cloud's mysql(due to business reasons) migration by using AWS DMS?or the target database should be inside AWS RDS?The source data size is close to 60GB and tables are close to 300.Please advice

Answer (score 0):

the target database should be inside AWS RDS.

Comment: What about source database?will RDS support if it the source database is outside of RDS?Can we do migration from source outside RDS to target inside RDS?

Comment: The source database can be anywhere.